# retrieve all whose `date` is within last 6 minutes

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a `Product` collection stored in MongoDB. It has a attribute `date` :

```
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema<ProductAttrs>({
    date: {
        type: Date, 
        required: true,
    }
    ...
})
```

I would like to retrieve all products whose `date` is within last 6 minutes comparing with current time. What is the efficient way to retrieve that in mongoose ?

I am using express.js + typescript + mongoose v5.11 in my project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use Mongoose to search every record where the time is greater than `now - 6 minutes`.
I have no way to test it, but the query should look something like this:

```
const sixMinutes = (6*60*1000); // 6 minutes
let sixMinutesAgo = new Date();
sixMinutesAgo.setTime(sixMinutesAgo.getTime() - sixMinutes);

const products = Product.find({ 
  date: {
        $gte: sixMinutesAgo
        }
  })
```

Comment: It was so simple, shame on me... +1 deserved ;)

Answer (score 1):

If your MongoDB server version is 5.0 you could use the new operator [`$dateDiff`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/dateDiff/). In this case it is very handy and you do not even need an `aggregate`:

```
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$lte": [
      {
        "$dateDiff": {
          startDate: "$date",
          endDate: new Date(),
          unit: "minute"
        }
      },
      6
    ]
  }
})
```

It allows you to specify the `unit` field, which makes the query very straightforward in my opinion.

[`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) evaluates an expression and returns `true` or `false`, just that. If the expression result is true then the row is returned, otherwise it is not.

[`$lte`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lte/#mongodb-expression-exp.-lte) means *less than or equal* (the `<=` operator) and it returns true only when the first argument is *less than or equal* the second operator. Basically, this is what it does in pseudocode:

```
foreach doc in collection
    if (minute)(currentDate - document.date) <= 6 then
        return document
```

Comment: Thanks, could you please explain a bit what is the `$expr` & `$lte` keywords? Sorry I am a newbie in MongoDB.

Comment: @pasine answer should probably be the accepted one.

Comment: yes, :) very straight forward. But nice to hear your solution as well! Thanks!